# SSH remote forward to docker host?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, docker

I'm using Docker on my local Mac, but I frequently need to share my work with others who are not on the same network.  In order to do so, I use `ssh` to forward a port from an AWS instance to my local machine.

The issue I'm running into is that the Docker instance is not a static IP.  I currently have this in my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
RemoteForward 0.0.0.0:8001 192.168.99.100:80
```

This works, but it causes problems when the virtual machine boots to a different IP.  What I'd like to do is something along the lines of:

```
RemoteForward 0.0.0.0:8001 ${DOCKER_IP}:80
```

This would allow me to set the `$DOCKER_IP` environment variable, and have it always connect and forward to the correct place.

Comment: Can you set the VM to use a static IP?

Comment: @Daniel No, there are multiple virtual machines on my system which it may need to point at.  For example, I am currently testing with `docker-swarm`.

Comment: Ah I see.  How do you invoke SSH?

Comment: Because this page:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Remote_Port_Forwarding should help you a lot.  It doesn't appear to specify anything more than ports and localhost (ad obviously the user@domain).

Comment: That would work if it was on `localhost`, but because it's off on a virtual machine, it causes problems.  and I'm just running `ssh flashlight`, and letting the config file take care of it.  I don't think I could get others in the office to type out an IP to save their lives.

Comment: have you considered having a DNS server running that keeps track of its IP?

Comment: You could also use a script to push the VM's IP out to clients.